# How can I make variable local in a buffer with global default in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

In .emacs I have variable defined as:

```
(setq-default prevent-highlight-symbol-mode nil)
```

I use it to disable red tabs:

```
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (if (and (null (memql major-mode highlight-chars-disable))
                     (not prevent-highlight-symbol-mode))
                 (hc-highlight-tabs))))
```

and use it in [project-specifics macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671045/function-that-remove-specific-lambda-from-a-hook-in-emacs)

```
(project-specifics "projects/some-project"
  (setq prevent-highlight-symbol-mode t)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
```

but when I open a file in some-project directory and I check for `prevent-highlight-symbol-mode` in any buffer I've got `t` not `nil`, it's set globaly. How can I make that variable local in a buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make-local-variable` makes a variable have a local binding in the current buffer.

`make-variable-buffer-local` makes a variable have a local binding in all buffers (even future ones).

If you have done `(make-local-variable 'A-VAR)` in the current buffer then `(setq A-VAR A-VALUE)` sets the local value.  You can also do it using just `(set (make-local-variable 'A-VAR) A-VALUE)`.

Comment: And if your code can safely break compatibility with Emacs versions prior to 24.3, you can use `setq-local` and `defvar-local`.

Comment: Can I run `make-variable-buffer-local` with `nil` in .emacs and `make-local-variable` in specific hook with `t`? Will all buffers exept that  with `t` have `nil`?

Comment: You typically don't mix them. `make-variable-buffer-local` takes one argument, a variable. When called, it will ensure that if you ever set that variable using `setq`, it automatically becomes buffer-local.

Comment: It work, but now I have different problem with order.