# How to highlight tab characters for files from specific project in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, whitespace, font-lock

I have this code to highlight tab characters and want to disable them using project-specifics macro:

```
(require 'highlight-chars)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'prevent-highlight-tabs)
(setq highlight-chars-disable '(term-mode erc-mode fundamental-mode))
(setq-default prevent-highlight-tabs nil)
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (message "lock")
            (when (and (null (memql major-mode highlight-chars-disable))
                       (not prevent-highlight-tabs))
              (message "%s" prevent-highlight-tabs)
              (hc-highlight-tabs))))
(custom-set-faces '(hc-tab ((t (:background "red")))))
```

and `project-specifics` is a macro that define add `find-file-hook` and `dired-after-readin-hook` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671045/function-that-remove-specific-lambda-from-a-hook-in-emacs)

```
(project-specifics "projects/test"
  (message "specific")
  (setq prevent-highlight-tabs t)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
```

What I wanted to do is disable red tabs (I want them because in most projects I want only spaces, and want to see tabs) for files in project/test, but I have a problem because the code from `font-lock-mode-hook` is executing before `project-specifics` (find-file-hook), and prevent-highlight-tabs is always nil in font-lock-mode-hook. Why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: The in-built `whitespace-mode` might be useful to you. (It might also be over-kill and over-complicated for your needs, but is certainly worth playing with.)

Comment: @phils I wanted to use whitespace-mode in the first try, but then when someone suggest to use `highlight-chars` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing seems convoluted.

And it is partly undefined (here) - e.g., what is the major mode `highlight-chars-disable`?  That is not defined in library [highlight-chars.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/highlight-chars.el), and it doesn't sound like something that would be a good candidate for a **major** mode.

See the `Commentary` of library [highlight-chars.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/highlight-chars.el) for suggestions.

Something like this, perhaps (and you would put property `prevent-highlight-tabs` on any major-mode symbols you like:

```
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
          (lambda () (unless (get major-mode 'prevent-highlight-tabs)
                       (hc-highlight-tabs))))
```

Or something like this (from the `Commentary`):

```
(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (eq major-mode 'THE-MODE)
              (remove-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)
              (hc-dont-highlight-tabs)))
          'APPEND)
```

Comment: sorry didn't included `highlight-chars-disable`, it's a list of modes that should not have marked tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you place your settings in `.dir-locals.el` as described in [Per-Directory Local Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).